# Laravel cache is supposed to remember my API Secret for 1 hour, but it doesn't

Tags: laravel, caching

I'm trying to get a token from external API. Token lasts 1h, so I would like to put it in cache with a duration of 1 hour.

```
$seconds = 60*60;
$token = Cache::remember('nova_api_token', $seconds, function () use ($request, $credentials) {
            try {
                $response = Http::asForm()
                    ->withHeaders(["Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"])
                    ->withBasicAuth($credentials->nova_id, $credentials->nova_secret)
                    ->post(config('nova.url') . "/v1/oauth2/token", [
                        "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
                    ]);
                $body = json_decode($response->body());
                return $body->access_token;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
            }
        });
        return $token;
```

I can get my token, but each time I send a post request, I get a different token.

What I expect is that the token would be the same during 1 hour.

Why is it happening ?

Comment: What do you mean with: _but each time I send a post request, I get a different token_? When you call `Cache::get('nova_api_token');` mulitple times, does it return a new token each time?

Comment: no, I never call Cache::get . I call Cache::remember, which is supposed to call Cache::get('nova_api_token') and if key doesn't exists, it will execute the query with this key. --> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#retrieve-store

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant that after you do the first request and it generates the token, when you run `Cache::get('nova_api_token');` in tinker, does it return null or the api token? Just to make sure that the value is actually stored in the cache.

Comment: Yes, with Tinker, I get null. I also checked my redis instance, and I have no key "nova_api_key"

Comment: Might be that your redis connection is not properly configured in Laravel, If you run `Cache::set('test', 123);` in tinker do you get an exception or does it write it into the cache correctly? Seems weird that it doesn't write anything into redis but doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: when I do: Cache::set('test', 123), it returns true, and after, I can get it with >>> Cache::get('test'); so it seems to be working

Comment: when I do $token = Cache::remember('nova_api_token', $seconds, function () {
                return 1;
            }); it still doesn't write a key 'nova-api_token'

Comment: Hm, are you sure this code is actually being run when you are making a request?

Comment: what do you mean ? yes, it must be, because I get a working token.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is the try/catch block as an interior function that causes problems try refactoring to:

```
try {               
  $seconds = 60*60;
  $token = Cache::remember('nova_api_token', $seconds, function () use ($request, $credentials) {
        $response = Http::asForm()
                ->withHeaders(["Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"])
                ->withBasicAuth($credentials->nova_id, $credentials->nova_secret)
                ->post(config('nova.url') . "/v1/oauth2/token", [
                    "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
                ]);
       $body = json_decode($response->body());
       return $body->access_token;
    });
    return $token;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
```

Comment: I removed try catch , and it doesn't change anything... not working

Comment: Before returning the token, can you try dumping the cache to see if it was set?

dd(Cache::get('nova_api_token'));

Comment: when I execute this dd() before Cache::remember, I get null, but when I execute after cache::remember, it returns the token

Comment: Did you run php artisan cache:clear after the refactor?

Answer (score 0):

Try with rememberForever and see if it is stored in redis.
And I would recommend using now()->addHour() instead of 60 * 60 as the function accepts timestamps as well.

Comment: I used Cache::rememberForever with dump(Cache::get('nova_api_token')); before and after. The one before is always null, which means it doesn't write to the cache :( will try a put()

Comment: Try with removing all code inside Cache::remember() and just return 1 and see if it is stored, if you are absolutely sure that redis is working then it's a problem with that code.

Comment: it seems that when I do it with Tinker, it will remember the token, but when I invoke it from postman, it will not remember it...

Comment: Try changing the name of the cache object: "nova_api_token".